# Syncml device emulator

Tags: emulation, syncml

I have been trying to create a device simulator for SyncML. Input would be DevInf information, using which some test cases have to be run.

Been searching on the net for quite some time now, even tried funambol and syncevo, but could not acheive this. Funambol has no support, so dropped it. Code does not compile. Inactive.

Syncevo is quite good, command line based. But is very tightly coupled with the base and hacking the devinf is not a simple task.

Can you suggest a way of implementing this, i am out of ideas now.

Regards

PS: i also tried exploring for OMA-SCTS, but seems to be outdated. Latest version is not available.

Comment: I guess this is not the right forum or a very popular topic to get reply on. :(

Comment: I wonder how people developing syncml clients and servers perform regression with every release. Cant expect it to be via black box. Has to be some automated process for verify clients and servers changes.

Comment: Syncml is nothing more than xml. You would just have a dtd or schema and validate against it.